# Django redirect to `tel` url yields `SuspiciousOperation`

Tags: django, redirect

I'm writing a little website that logs when users click on a link (which is obviously a telephone number). It does this through a view, which then redirects to that telephone number.

Naturally, (I agree this should be default behavior) Django sees that as a `SuspiciousOperation`. In my case, I'm doing it intentionally. How can I suppress this error and let the view resolve like I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root of your app that redirects to tel: uris:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirectBase
HttpResponseRedirectBase.allowed_schemes += ['tel']
```

Comment: Yes, this worked nicely. I ended up making a subclass of HttpResponseRedirect similar to what you did here. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, this is not a subclass, but enables tel: schemes globally. this is important if you're using generic views that return redirects.

Comment: Correct, your solution wasn't a subclass, but mine was. I ended up doing that so the `SuspiciousOperation` was not suppressed for the whole site, but just for my one view that needed it.

Answer (score 8):

I had cannot import name HttpResponseRedirectBase error with the first answer. I managed to do (nearly) as expected with :

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirectBase
HttpResponseRedirectBase.allowed_schemes += ['tel']
```

Comment: You are repeating an existing answer, Why?

Comment: Because the existing answer made me have HttpResponseRedirectBase before the ".response" I added :-)

Comment: Is this a change that arises because of a newer version of Django?

Comment: I have no Idea. I use python 2.7 and Django 1.5, I don't know wether Thomas made a Typo or it was a django update...

Comment: I think this is a change in Django since I am upgrading from Django 1.4 to Django 2.1.7 this answer helped me, I think it warrants a separate question

Comment: Since the error is quite exactly the same, two answers is not useless _that_ useless. I could have add a comment, though.